# Linux OS crash randomly

Tags: linux, boot, crash

Randomly, when I tried to open the Linux native browser the computer froze and after a couple minutes went to black and is giving me the error message:

[256657.388021] nouveau E[Xorg[1344]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0001 [Xorg[1344]]

what exactly does this mean? Can I get out of it without restarting it?

Comment: What distro? Have you tried using the proprietary Nvidia drivers instead of Nouveau drivers, the proprietary ones are much better. Use the ones from your official repos if possible before trying the ones direct from Nvidia and check your distros forums for more information, sometimes the ones from Nvidia's website need to be tweaked a little depending on your distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your graphic card driver ("nouveau"). Possibly the browser want to use some acceleration, which are incorrectly coded in nouveau driver for your card.

Try to check if there is a new driver, or eventually disable some acceleration (until there will be a new driver).